# Is there a way to use Logic Pro plugins to modulate pitch?

Tags: logic-pro, plugins, modulation

I would like to attach an LFO to one of my tracks and have it modulate pitch/frequency. Is there any way to accomplish this using the factory plug-ins in Logic Pro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

The tape delay (as well as other delays) has an LFO that modulates the delay time, in turn this will result in a modulation of pitch. Just keep the output on 100% wet, but use the delay as an insert (not a send).